# How can I format dart code in sublime text

Tags: flutter, dart, sublimetext3, formatter, dartfmt

I downloaded flutter with dart inside, and start coding on sublime text but when I press formatt code it gives me wrong message which is **"formatter for this type file (dart) not found."** but when I run this command "dart format . " in the directory the code will be formatted, my question is how can I format code inside sublime instead of write that command in cmd?

note:

- when I run `dart --version` in cmd it show its version but if I run `dartfmt --version` it doesn't recognize it as well as I downloaded codeformatter package

Comment: Try `dart format --version`

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the plugin [formatter](https://github.com/bitst0rm-pub/Formatter) specifically, you can't, dart is not supported but you can easily implement it with the instructions on the git page.

If you don't know/want do it yourself just do this two things:

Create the file `${packages}/Formatter/modules/formatter_dartformat.py` with this code (the file is located in `%APPDATA%/Sublime Text/Packages/Formatter/modules` on windows).

```py
import logging
from ..core import common

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

EXECUTABLES = ['dart']
MODULE_CONFIG = {
    'name': 'DartFormat', 
    'source': 'https://dart.dev/tools/dart-format', 

    'uid': 'dartformat', 
    'type': 'beautifier',                  
    'syntaxes': ['dart'], 

    'executable_path': '',
    'args': ['format'],
}

class DartformatFormatter:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.view = kwargs.get('view', None)
        self.uid = kwargs.get('uid', None)
        self.region = kwargs.get('region', None)
        self.is_selected = kwargs.get('is_selected', False)
        self.pathinfo = common.get_pathinfo(self.view.file_name())

    def get_cmd(self):
        executable = common.get_executable(
            self.view, self.uid, EXECUTABLES, runtime_type=None
        )

        if executable is not None: 
            args = common.get_args(self.uid)
            
            cmd = [executable]
            cmd.extend(args or MODULE_CONFIG['args'])
            
            return cmd
        else:
            return None


    def format(self, text):
        cmd = self.get_cmd()
        log.debug('Current arguments: %s', cmd)
        cmd = common.set_fix_cmds(cmd, self.uid)
        if not cmd:
            return None

        try:
            proc = common.exec_cmd(cmd, self.pathinfo['cwd'])
            stdout, stderr = proc.communicate(text.encode('utf-8'))

            errno = proc.returncode
            if errno > 0:
                log.error(
                    'File not formatted due to an error (errno=%d): "%s"', 
                    errno, stderr.decode('utf-8')
                )
            else:
                return stdout.decode('utf-8')
        except OSError:
            log.error(
                'An error occurred while executing the command: %s', 
                ' '.join(cmd)
            )

        return None
```

Then add the module to the config file at `${packages}/User/Formatter.sublime-settings`.

```json
{
    // The other variables

    "formatters": {

        "dartformat": {
            "disable": false,
            "format_on_save": false,
            "syntaxes": ["dart"],
            "args": ["format", "-l", "360"],
            "executable_path": "O:/Flutter/bin/dart",
        },

        // The other formatters that you may have
    }
}
```